# iOS one month from current Date.

Tags: ios, date, calendar, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to get one month from the current date.

Below is what I have and it is returning: `4027-09-24 16:59:00 +0000`. currentDate is right. What's going on?

```
// Get todays date to set the monthly subscription expiration date
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Current Date = %@", currentDate);
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
dateComponents.month = dateComponents.month + 1;
NSDate *currentDatePlus1Month = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:currentDate options:0];
NSLog(@"Date = %@", currentDatePlus1Month);
```

Comment: Your code *adds* 2013 years, 11 months, ... to the current date.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
// Get todays date to set the monthly subscription expiration date
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Current Date = %@", currentDate);

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
dateComponents.month = 1;

NSDate *currentDatePlus1Month = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:currentDate options:0];
NSLog(@"Date = %@", currentDatePlus1Month);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate]; 
  // Get necessary date components

[components month]; //gives you month

[components day]; //gives you day

[components year]; //gives you year
```